# Covariance matrix is always non-negative definite

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

Muirhead<sup>1</sup> shows that $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix if and only if $\Sigma$ is non-negative definite. The first part of the proof is written below.

> \begin{align}
> \newcommand{\Var}{{\rm Var}}
> \Var(\alpha^Tx) &= E[(\alpha^Tx - \alpha^T\mu)^2]  \\[3pt]
> &=E[(\alpha^T(x - \mu))^2]  \\[3pt]
> &=E[\alpha^T(x - \mu)(x - \mu)^T\alpha]  \\[3pt]
> &=\alpha^T\Sigma\alpha  \\[3pt]
> &\ge 0
> \end{align}

Note that both $x$ and $\mu$ are vectors. I'm having some trouble understanding the first equality. Since for any vector $y$, the the variance is given by:

$$\Var(y) = E[(y-\mu)^2]$$

I would expect that the variance for $\alpha^Ty$ would simply be:

$$\Var(y) = E[(\alpha^Ty-\mu)^2]$$.

<sup>1</sup> *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory*, 2005

Comment: There are more than one math typos in your expressions, that make it also hard to underastand where your difficulty lies. Please correct.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos: Correted. Can you help me now?

Comment: Either there are still typos or you are trying to tell us $\mu$ and $\alpha^\prime\mu$ must have the same expectation, which obviously is not generally true.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, there was a missing bracket in second line. Does your assertion still confirms?

Comment: @gung: Are you saying I should refuse the answer?

Comment: No, @Eduardo. That comment wasn't directed towards you. This thread was in the close vote queue. I was making an argument to future reviewers that this question needn't be closed as too unclear to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E(x)=\mu$. Then it follows, that $E(\alpha^\prime x)=\alpha^\prime \mu$ due to linearity. By definition $Var(\alpha^\prime x) = E((\alpha'x-E(\alpha'x))^2)=E((\alpha'x-\alpha'\mu)^2)$. In your first line you forgot the squared (actually it is in the book), and your misunderstanding was, that the expected value of $x$ is $\mu$, not of $\alpha^\prime x$.

EDIT: Moreover you missed a bracket in your third line.